# Differential Amplifier with Global Negative Feedback

Tags: amplifier, audio, feedback, differential

This question refers to audio amplifier design, using BJTs only.

I am wondering how differential stage amplifier plays an important role in hi-fi audio amplifiers.
According to this book (where picture was copied from) I have, a part of output signal is feeding the base of Q2. Q1 and Q2 somehow amplify input signal and at the same time cancel out some of distortion that is being brought back from the output to the differential input stage of amplifier.

- I want to understand the process of this differential stage and how it manages to cancel out some of the output distortion.

[image]

I almost completely understand functions of other transistor stages so there is no need for explaining how the whole circuit works.

*Source: G. Randy Slone : High Power Audio Amplifier Construction Manual

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrating op amp feedback without control theory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50460/illustrating-op-amp-feedback-without-control-theory).  Your question is really about what negative feedback is and how it works.  See my detailed answer to the above question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Maybe just a part of my question refers to nfb. I was mostly interested of how Q1 and Q2 prevent distortions coming from the output.

Comment: The negative feedback reduces the distortion, not the differential pair by itself. The differential pair act as an error amplifier. He compares the input signal (not distorted one) with the output signal. So, the error signal is created to cancel the distortion. Exactly in the same way as a negative feedback "brings back" the output signal to the equilibrium state (V"+" = V"-"). The negative feedback does not distinguish between types of disturbances.

Comment: If for some reason the Vout is different than expected the negative feedback will correct it. If Vout is larger than expected (Vin) the Q2 will reduce his IC current. But in the same time, the Q1 Ic current will goes up. Q3 and Q4 current will also increase so the Vout will drop.

Comment: Note how the name "differential amplifier" relates to the fact that the amplifier (with a differential pair at its input) **amplifies the difference (voltage)** at its input. By amplifying the difference and feeding it back as negative feedback, the difference is minimized. And zero difference means no distortion.

Comment: In all cases and for each amplifier type the effect of negative feedback always reduces non-linear distortions. This was proven - independent on a particular topology - for all active blocks with negative feedback (H. Black in the 1930th).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Seems logical to me. But how does Q2 do anything since there is no output taken on that device? Or does the Q2 transistor affects the Q1 transistor?

Comment: *But how does Q2 do anything since there is no output taken on that device?* There is! Through the feedback network (basically R5 and R7+C6) this is a voltage divider which takes the output voltage, divides it (by roughly 470/10470) and feeds that to Q2. I hope you understand that at the base of Q2 there is a divided-down version of the output voltage which the amplifier tries to match (compare, amplify difference) with the input voltage which is at the base of Q1.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you in my previous comment! What you mean: the collector current of Q2 is not used! That's correct but it does not matter. The **sum** of the collector current of Q1 and Q2 **remains constant**. So if Ic_Q2 is **a bit larger** then Ic_Q1 will be **a bit smaller**. So we can "throw away" Ic_Q2 because Ic_Q1 contains **the same information**. Why is Ic_Q1 + Ic_Q2 constant? Because of R1, it forces a nearly constant current into Q1 + Q2.

Comment: Ideally R1 should be a current source but since there's almost 50 V across it, it will be good enough. The voltage at the emitters of Q1 and Q2 does not vary much (very little compared to 50 V) so the current will be reasonably constant.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, R1 should be replaced by constant current source and R3&R4 should also be replaced with current mirrors for optimal balance.

Comment: You could try that in a simulator and see how much difference it makes. My bet: it will not make a lot of difference. As long as the open-loop gain is much higher than the closed-loop gain then any imbalances in the loop are suppressed.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  You said this: "So if Ic_Q2 is a bit larger then Ic_Q1 will be a bit smaller.", so that means if Vbe_Q2 increases a bit more then Vbe_Q1 will decrease for the same amount?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The original question asked about "cancelling output distortion". This answer shows the diffpair **ADDS** its own distortion, uncancelable distortion.

with 200 milliwatt power dissipation in your diffpair, you will experience lots
of thermal distortion. Put in a clean square wave (into the actual circuit) and examine the overshoots (or undershoots) on pulse leading edges.

You can model this in SPICE, using voltage-controlled-voltage-sources to modulate a DC voltage in series with base or with emitter, that source changing
-2 milliVolts per degree Centigrade of collector heating.

Now if you just had a good thermal model of those transistors.

Assume each is 100 micron cube.
1u cube is 11.4 nanoseconds
10u cube is 1140 nanoseconds
100u cube is 114000 nanoseconds (114 microSeconds)

Given 4+ milliamp through R1, and 50 volts Vce across each of Q1 and Q2, there is at least 200milliWatts total in those 2 devices.

You care about the transient thermal resistance.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this needs a bit of a clean-up. Mind the units too: "V" or "volt" (units named after a person are capitalised only when abbreviated), "s" or "second" and "centigrade".

Comment: I don't know where you got 300mW from. None of this has anything to do with the question that was asked.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question..